# Finding Average Nearest Neighbor when multiple points are stacked with similar XYZ

Tags: arcgis-pro, nearest-neighbor, workflow

I routinely run the average nearest neighbor tool in ArcGIS Pro but I do a lot of front end massaging my points file.
My current workflow:
I generate multiple points that run down a single drill hole trace. For example, it looks like a series of points that follow the trace of the continuous line (see image, cross section view) - resulting in a points table that has points with very similar XYZs. In short, I take an interval (0-5, 5-10) and create a point to represent the interval (2.5, 7.5). The final result is a table with HoleID | X | Y | Z where HoleID is non-unique.
I have tried to parse out these similar values in Pro, Access, or Excel but I don't seem to find any easy way to remove very similar values.

Is there a way to reduce how much the data needs to be massaged?

[image]

Comment: What is massaging?

Comment: Massaging the data means to manipulate it in some way.